# The word 'tag' in the documentation tour links to the tag 'tag' rather than the list of tags

Tags: feature-request, documentation

In the [documentation tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation), under the section 'How is documentation organised?', there is the following sentence:

> Practically all subjects have a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag) on Stack Overflow's Q&A already, so we group Documentation by those tags.

Note that the word 'tag' is linked to the actual SO tag [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag), as if the syntax `[tag:tag]` was used.

The word 'tag' should instead link to the [tag list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags), as users can browse the selection of avaliable tags.

Comment: Yes, also, somewhat related...  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328517/adding-tags-in-documentation-editor